# Any other option to get realtime data from server than API calls or Sockets?

Tags: websocket, real-time

Simple question, are there any other options how to fetch data from server to client to achieve realtime refresh (For example realtime table) other than:

1. Call API request inside some loop
2. Subscribe to realtime websocket server

I mean it as core options. Sure there are many libraries or patterns but seems they using one of those two methods.

Comment: There's SSE (Server Sent Events, a.k.a., EventSource), WebSockets and polling (short / long). Other then that, you'll be working with non-standard solutions (i.e., flash sockets, etc'). IMHO, WebSockets are the best for realtime updates and there are plenty of tools to make the development easy enough.

Answer (score 2):

For Web Applications (browser clients):

There's SSE (Server Sent Events, a.k.a., EventSource), WebSockets and polling (short / long).

Other then that, you'll be working with non-standard solutions (i.e., flash sockets, etc').

IMHO, WebSockets are the best for realtime updates and there are plenty of tools to make the development easy enough.